# How to have the same output if i add LIKE in my query

Tags: mysql

Table 1

```
  *Table shortlisted_details*
  ---------------------------
  id    employee_id    shortlisted_master_id
  ---------------------------------------------
  1        12117        136
  2        13133        136
  3        11114        136 
  4        12117        116
  5        12117        203
```

Table 2

```
  *Table shortlisted_master*
  ------------------------
  id    filter_details_id
  -------------------------
  1      136
  2      162
  3      169
  4      116
  5      203
```

Table 3

```
 *Table employees*
 ---------------
 id     first_name
 ------------------
 12117  Faith
 13133  David
 11114  Noel
```

This is my query

```
 SELECT COUNT(sd.id) as 'shortlisted_count',
    sm.filter_details_id as Filter_ID

    FROM shortlisted_details sd

    INNER JOIN employees e ON e.id= sd.employee_id

    INNER JOIN shortlisted_master sm ON sm.id=sd.shortlisted_master_id

    WHERE sd.is_disqualified=0 AND sm.filter_details_id = 136

        GROUP BY sm.id
```

This is the output

```
   *Result*
   shortlisted_count    Filter_ID
   ---------------------------------
   3                     136
```

but if I change the where into this  `" WHERE sd.is_disqualified=0 AND sm.filter_details_id = 136 AND e.first_name LIKE '%Faith%' "` this is the output of the query

```
   *Result*
   shortlisted_count    Filter_ID
   ---------------------------------
   1                     136
```

but I want to happen is the same output of the 1st output even if I add the LIKE

Comment: You are adding an extra condition, saying that the name should contain "Faith". "David and "Noel" doesn't contain "Faith", so you can't expect to have a count of 3.

Comment: As per sample data it seems you are joining it on wrong condition 
    `INNER JOIN shortlisted_master sm ON sm.id=sd.shortlisted_master_id`

Comment: Please show the tables with some data and also show desired output. It's hard to understand exactly what you want to accomplish.